# rails 4 content_tag nested not displaying html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display an html table body content in my view from an helper

```
   .../...
  <tbody>
      <% display_pg_table_rows(@headings, @rows) %>
  </tbody>
  .../...

  # helpers/sheets_helper.rb

    module SheetsHelper
      def display_pg_table_rows(headings, rows)
        rows.collect do |row|
          content_tag(:tr, class: "<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>") {
          headings.collect do |heading|
            concat content_tag(:td, "xxxx", class: "center")
          end
        }
      end
    end
```

but nothing is displayed in the view ... what could be wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "=" in the <%= tag before display_pg_table_rows.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I don't think so... should not be <%=  but as written a <¨ 
found the issue  in between ..

Comment: OK, I see what you're doing now.  Glad you fixed it, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

missing the initial concat for the tr tag !

```
module SheetsHelper
  def display_pg_table_rows(headings, rows)
    rows.collect do |row|
      concat content_tag(:tr, class: "<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>") {
      headings.collect do |heading|
        concat content_tag(:td, "xxxx", class: "center")
      end
    }
  end
end
```